# Spring inject dependency for constructors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm planning to create my objects in my Spring MVC using the below setup but How can I inject values to my MyService ie; instantiate the object with default value...

```
public class MyController {

    private MyService myService;


    @Autowired
    public void setMyService(MyService aService) { // autowired by Spring
        this.myService = aService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/blah")
    public String someAction()
    {
        // do something here
        myService.foo();

        return "someView";
    }
}
```

MyService

```
class Myservice(){
     String servicename;
     public Myservice(servicename){
           this.servicename = servicename;
     }

}
```

Without Spring

```
  MyService first = new MyService("firstservice");
  MyService second = new MyService("secondservice");
```

Comment: Have you declared a `Myservice` bean?

Comment: Yes...I declared it with @Component...

Comment: And you want a default or configurable value for `servicename`?

Comment: yes...thats correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your constructor with `@Autowired` to mark it as the constructor to use and its parameter with `@Value` to indicate the value to use.

```
@Autowired 
public Myservice(@Value("example") String servicename){
```

Or use a placeholder

```
@Autowired 
public Myservice(@Value("${placeholder.key}") String servicename){
```

Comment: I would like to have as placeholder as the value will be varying each time I instantiate..but how can I set the value..

Comment: @user1050619 Can you edit your question and show us what you mean by _each time I instantiate_?

Comment: @user1050619 (Please stop using `...` for everything.) It's now unclear to me what you want to do? Are you going to use prototype beans? A `@Component` bean without an explicit scope is a singleton. There's only one being created with whatever value you specify with `@Value` or a bean with `@Autowired`.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios..@Component & @Prototype is much clear now...I think thats where I had some confusion..btwn..I have to add "..." to beat the min len validation set...

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, your exam are wrong on using Spring DI. To inject Myservice type to another You should declare MyService as a interface instead:

```
interface Myservice(){         
    public void foo();
}
```

After that, declare an implementation of this interface (again, use Spring DI to inject String type):

```
    class BarService() implements Myservice{
        String servicename;

        @Autowired
        public Myservice(@Value("servicename") String servicename){
             this.servicename = servicename;
        }
        public void foo(){

        }

   }
```

Comment: what wrong? If you think it's not useful, give me a reason please!

Comment: You are so selfish, you have done that just because i have said "your exam are wrong".
Why is there a person that does not feel ashamed to do it?